# Why does Google Pagespeed Insights tell us that the same exact javascript takes 4x longer to execute on mobile than on desktop?

Tags: javascript, performance, mobile, desktop

We are trying to improve our Google Pagespeed Insights score on mobile devices, and have stumbled on measurements where mobile is performing worse than desktop. But those measurements confuse us, and we are looking for help understanding them.

Our desktop score is solid, including the "Javascript execution time" measurement. However the "Javascript execution time" measurement on mobile is very bad. When we look at the scripts on both mobile and desktop, we see the same scripts listed (a lot of the usual suspects, like our javascript framework, jquery libraries, recaptcha, et cetera). But on mobile both the evaluation time and parse time were 5-7 times longer than on desktop. WE only have a single responsive website, and have verified that we are loading the exact same javascript resources on mobile as on desktop. So why would these times be so different on mobile?

```
                  | mobile                  | desktop
resource          | eval    parse   total   | eval    parse   total
--------------------------------------------------------------------
recaptcha__en.js  | 179ms   61ms    266ms   | 44ms    16ms    66ms
facebook_sdk.js   | 217ms   31ms    251ms   | 43ms    7ms     51ms
everything else   | 859ms   10ms    2195ms  | 185ms   2ms     497ms
```

We have attempted to research best-practices on mobile javascript: deferring what we can, dynamically loading what we can, et cetera. But when it comes down to it, the main problem seems to be that the exact same third-party scripts are performing much worse on mobile than on desktop, and we have no idea why or what we can do to remedy this.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why would you expect a typical phone to perform comparably to a modern laptop/desktop system? Also the table you posted indicates a situation opposite to your described problem; did you mis-label it?

Comment: Thanks, I did mis-label it. I corrected those labels. As for your first question, that's a fair point. Certainly a mobile device is going to have reduced computational power - but taking 4x longer to execute javascript still seemed surprising for some reason.

Would your expectation be that a single javascript resource would take 4x longer to execute on a typical mobile device than on a desktop device?

Comment: It's entirely possible that there are optimizations that make sense for an x86 CPU that simply don't for a Snapdragon (or whatever). Surely the JavaScript runtime systems in mobile browsers are not exactly the same as those in desktop browsers. And it looks to me like your numbers speak for themselves.